# Spring bean destroy method as a non class method

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a class that is a part of the 3-rd party library.
I created a bean from this class using `@Bean` annotation. And there is `destroyMethod` parameter that is using for the setting method that should be called before bean will be destroyed.

I have to destroy in another way since there is no such method in the class.
So is there any way to implement destroy logic out of class.

> I understand that there is a way with creating a proxy for this bean and put destroy method there. But I am looking for a more readable way.

Comment: I would just put a `@PreDestroy` on the `@Configuration` responsible for declaring the bean.

Comment: @Michael no tempted to write an answer ?

Comment: Thanks, @Michael, are you sure this method will run before bean will be destroyed?

Comment: Can you add an example code for this? I can't seem to follow: what's the `destroyMethod`, and how do you intend to call it if it's not on the bean?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this?

```
class BeanImpl extends BeanThirdParty {
   public void close() {
      ...
   }
}
```

and in config file you can have:

```
@Bean(destroyMethod="close")
public BeanThirdParty beanThirdParty() {
   return new BeanImpl();
}
```

In case that `BeanThirdParty` is final you can to this:

```
class BeanImpl {
   private BeanThirdParty beanThirdParty;
   public void close() {
     beanThirdParty.something()//and here we came to your proxy solution :)
   }
}
```

But if you cannot edit or extend class from third party lib I don't see any other way to implement this feature. And this one with proxy seems fine.

Comment: What if it's declared as final, or the concrete class is not exposed at all?

Comment: Yes, it is final. I can use delegation over inheritance. It will be similar to the proxy way.